# SELECT INTO variable in MySQL - how to check that result exists and how to execute IF statements using the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How I can check, in a stored procedure, that result of query

```
SELECT start_date_time,length_time_interval_s FROM table LIMIT 1 INTO @date1, @length1
```

is some data (that is, select returned a match), that data matches (or not) some other data, and make actions based on the check outcome? I need to do something like

- if data is returned (row is found)

  - if varaibles @date1 and @length1 equal to previously set @date2 and @length2

    - do insert 1
  - else (if variables are not equal to @date2 and @length2)

    - do insert 2
- else (if data is not returned, 0 rows)

  - do insert 3

Also, do I have to pre-declare @date1 and @length1 or they will be declared during select? It is a bit unclear from docs.

Comment: You have answered your own question with pseudo-code that can easily be turned into SQL statements.

Question though, where are your `date2` and `length2` parameters defined? Are they stored procedure arguments?

Comment: @JonathonOgden basically my question is what SQL statements I should write in  e.g. first check

Comment: Try [IS NOT NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null). `IF @date1 IS NOT NULL AND @length1 IS NOT NULL THEN`.

Comment: Quick response to one of your questions: you don't have to declare the variables before use in your select statement.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure should do what you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (IN date2 DATETIME, IN length2 DATETIME)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE date1   DATETIME;
    DECLARE length1 DATETIME;
    DECLARE found   INTEGER DEFAULT TRUE;

    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT start_date_time, length_time_interval_s
        FROM table;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
      SET found = FALSE;

    OPEN cursor1;
    FETCH cursor1 INTO date1, length1;

    IF found THEN
      IF date1 IS NULL or length1 IS NULL OR date1 <> date2 OR length1 <> length2 THEN
        -- perform insert2
      ELSE
        -- perform insert1
      END IF;
    ELSE
      -- perform insert3
    END IF;

    CLOSE cursor1;
  END;
```

As usual, I leave both error handling and the squashing of syntactic bugs as an exercise for the reader.

One potential gotcha: the `IF` condition assumes that `table,start_date_time` and `table.length_time_interval_s` may be **`NULL`**, and that `date2` and `time2` may not. If the rules were different, the conditional expression would also need to change.

If you would like me to explain any part of my code I shall be happy to do so after a good night's rest.

Answer (score 0):

Use If Exists to check, if data is returned (row is found) like

```
If Exists (SELECT start_date_time,length_time_interval_s FROM table LIMIT 1 INTO @date1, @length1)
Then
        Some condition for insert1 or insert2
Else
        Insert3
End If
```